# WinForms (C#) Databinding Object to Checkbox.Checked Property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I'm writing a WinForms app, and am trying to bind a boolean property on a .NET object to a Checkbox's "checked" property. I am successfully creating the binding, but when I change the source property's value from false to true (I have a button that toggles it), the checkbox's "checked" property does not reflect that change.

```
if (chkPreRun.DataBindings["Checked"] == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Adding chkPreRun databinding");
    Binding _binding = chkPreRun.DataBindings.Add("Checked", NwmConfig, "PreRun")

    // Added this just to ensure that these were being set properly
    _binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    _binding.ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
}
```

I am able to successfully bind the text property to the value of a TextBox, for example. I'm not sure what I'm missing while binding to the "Checked" property, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to work, the source must have either a `PreRunChanged` event (`EventHandler`) that is getting fired, or it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (including for this property). Or as an edge-case, must have a *custom* `PropertyDescriptor` implementation that supports notification (but that is very rare.

Does your code have a `PreRunChanged` ? Does it get raised at the appropriate time?

(the UI doesn't poll for changes; it only knows about changes via the notification events)

Comment: Marc,

I do not have the event handler you mentioned, nor do I implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Your post at least points me in the right direction.

I should probably do some more reading up on DataBinding.

Thanks for the answer.

-Trevor

Comment: Looks like INotifyPropertyChanged will do exactly what I need it to.